# Why can't include <android/input.h> when can include <android/log.h> in Android NDK programming?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-framework

There is `input.h`, `bitmap.h`,`log.h` file in `android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/android/`, but when I `#include <android/input.h>` and `#include <android/bitmap.h>`, it throws error: `fatal error: android/input.h: No such file or directory`, meanwhile if I `#include <android/log.h>`, no problem there. Does anyone know why?

And I have another problem, there is `RefBase.h` in `android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/rs/cpp/util/RefBase.h`, but I can't include it with `#include rs/cpp/util/RefBase.h`, why?

I'll very appreciate if you can help!

Answer (score 2):

What platform are you targetting in your project?

The content of platforms/android-19 is only available if you target API level 19 or higher, either in your AndroidManifest.xml, or by adding APP_PLATFORM to your Application.mk.

It is likely that you're compiling your code targetting a lower API level, in which case these headers are simply not available.

is part of API level 3 (the minimum one) and all above, that's why you can always include it.